# Is there a good way of setting a model attribute to be an instance of another model?

Tags: plugin-development, models, attribute

I have an API call to make that needs a particular format of data shown below. The **person** and **addresses** attributes are currently set as **Mixed** *AttributeTypes* and I'll need to create a manual validation method on the model to make sure they are correctly formatted and populated:

```
$requestModel = Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel::populateModel([
    'username'  => 'russ01@someemail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'person' => [
        'firstName' => 'Sammy',
        'lastName' => 'Davis Junior'
    ], 'addresses' => [
        [
            'line1' => 'Any House',
            'line2' => 'Any Road',
            'town' => 'Anyville',
            'postcode' => 'AB1 1AB',
            'country' => 'GB',
            'stateCode' => 'AL'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

What I'm wondering is if **person** and **addresses** should be models in their own right, something like this for **person**:

```
$person = Micros_GuestPersonModel::populateModel([
    'firstName' => 'Sammy',
    'lastName' => 'Davis Junior'
]);

$requestModel = Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel::populateModel([
    'username'  => 'russ01@fuel-digital.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'person' => $person,
    'addresses' => [
        [
            'line1' => 'Any House',
            'line2' => 'Any Road',
            'town' => 'Anyville',
            'postcode' => 'AB1 1AB',
            'country' => 'GB',
            'stateCode' => 'AL'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

I can't see a way to set a model attribute to be a particular class like *Micros_GuestPersonModel*, so I guess I could pass in the array of data from it like this:

```
$person = Micros_GuestPersonModel::populateModel([
    'firstName' => 'Sammy',
    'lastName' => 'Davis Junior'
]);

$requestModel = Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel::populateModel([
    'username'  => 'russ01@fuel-digital.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'person' => $person->getAttributes(),
    'addresses' => [
        [
            'line1' => 'Any House',
            'line2' => 'Any Road',
            'town' => 'Anyville',
            'postcode' => 'AB1 1AB',
            'country' => 'GB',
            'stateCode' => 'AL'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Can anybody offer advice here on how best to approach this kind of model setup?

==== EDIT =====

Here's my attempt at passing in a **Micros_GuestPersonModel** and validating it...

**Class *Micros_GuestPersonModel*:**

```
class Micros_GuestPersonModel extends BaseModel {

    protected function defineAttributes ()
    {
        return [
            'firstName' => [
                'type' => AttributeType::String, 'required' => TRUE
            ],
            'lastName' => [
                'type' => AttributeType::String, 'required' => TRUE
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

**Class *Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel*:**

```
class Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel extends BaseModel {

    protected function defineAttributes ()
    {
        return [
            'username' => [
                'type' => AttributeType::Email, 'required' => TRUE
            ],
            'password' => [
                'type' => AttributeType::String, 'required' => TRUE
            ],
            'person' => [
                'type' => AttributeType::Mixed, 'required' => TRUE
            ],
            'address' => [
                'type' => AttributeType::Mixed, 'required' => TRUE
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function rules ()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules[] = [ 'person', 'validatePerson' ];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function validatePerson ($attribute)
    {
        if ( ! $this->$attribute instanceof Micros_GuestPersonModel)
        {
            $this->addError($attribute, "Person should be an instance of Micros_GuestPersonModel");

            return;
        }

        if ( ! $this->$attribute->validate())
        {
            foreach ($this->$attribute->getErrors() as $errors)
            {
                foreach ($errors as $error)
                {
                    $this->addError($attribute, $error);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**And an example controller usage:**

```
    $person = Micros_GuestPersonModel::populateModel([
        'firstName' => '', // invalid as this is required
        'lastName' => 'Davis Junior'
    ]);

    $requestModel = Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel::populateModel([
        'username'  => 'russ01@fuel-digital.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'person' => $person,
        'addresses' => [
            [
                'line1' => 'Any House',
                'line2' => 'Any Road',
                'town' => 'Anyville',
                'postcode' => 'AB1 1AB',
                'country' => 'GB',
                'stateCode' => 'AL'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

I can then capture the errors as follows:

```
if ( ! $requestModel->validate())
{
    Craft::dd($requestModel->getErrors());
}
```

It works, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Micros_GuestRegistrationRequestModel`'s attribute definition, if you define `person` like so:

```
'person' => array(AttributeType::Mixed, 'model' => 'Micros_GuestPersonModel');
```

Craft should take care of ensuring `person` will be an instance of `Micros_GuestPersonModel`.

Comment: Great, thanks. Are there any validation helpers or is my validatePerson() method above the way to go?

Comment: Honestly, I can't recall if calling validate on the main model will run validation for attributes that have a model class. Would be easy to test, though.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work for me - I can pass anything into the attribute and all it seems to do is ensure something has been passed (required). It would be great if a model's validate method could also validate attribute models too at some point. I'll add that in the form of a custom validator for now.

Comment: Yeah, custom validation is the way to go for now, then. You can always add a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/)!

Comment: Done! Thanks Brad. Setting a model is pretty neat - I can see that if I pass an array it populates the model for me automatically, which saves some boilerplate :-)